# How to fit the content of the cells in this table?

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx, multirow, ltablex

Well, surely this is a duplicate, but I have troubles with the alignment of a huge table. In fact my problem is to determine the *width* of each column properly, especially when the columns are narrow, and the justification by default generates a rather unpleasant visual appearance. I also have the problem that the `multirow` package generates columns too narrow and I can't get a right presentation.

The only tool I use (so far) is `p{width}` that has the defect to justify the text of the column width and when it is *scarce*, the visual aspect is pretty bad. So the question is, in such cases, is there any alternative to adjust the width of a narrow column without being justified?

My MWE:

```
   \documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=letter,headings=small,bibliography=totoc,DIV=12,headsepline=true,titlepage=on]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{soul}   
    \usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel} 
    \usepackage{fontspec} 
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
    \usepackage{xunicode}    
    \setmainfont[
    ItalicFont = SourceSerifPro,
    ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2}
    ]{SourceSerifPro} 
    \setsansfont{SourceSansPro}
    \setmonofont{SourceCodePro}    
    \usepackage{xspace}
    \usepackage{xkeyval}
    \usepackage{array,multirow,multicol,rotating,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,ltablex,afterpage} 
    \newcolumntype{Z}{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
    %\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
    \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{@{}C@{}}{#1}}  
    \usepackage{rotating} 
    \usepackage{colortbl} 
    \usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx} 
    \sisetup{
    output-decimal-marker = {.},
    group-minimum-digits = 4,
    range-units = brackets,
    list-final-separator = { \translate{and} },
    list-pair-separator = { \translate{and} },
    %range-phrase = { \translate{to (numerical range)} },
    range-phrase={\,a\,}
    }
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \providetranslation [ to = Spanish ]
    { to~(numerical~range) } { a }%substitute the right word here
    \ExplSyntaxOff    
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
    \setcellgapes{1.5pt}

\begin{document}
    {
\captionof{table}{Gasoductos}
\label{tab:GasoIns}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{0.16\linewidth} p{0.2\linewidth} p{50pt}
S[table-format=4.1]
S[table-format=5.1]
S[table-format=7.1]
S[table-format=5.1]
p{50pt}
  @{}}
\toprule
Permisario & Localización & Inicio de  & {Longitud} & {Volumen} & {Volumen} & {Inversión\footnote{A millones de dólares de 2014.}} & Estatus \\
       &              & Operaciones &           &{Promedio} & {Promedio}&             &         \\
       &              &                    & {\si{\kilo\metre}} & {\si{\milli\metre^3\day}} & {(MMpcd)} & {(Mdd)} \\                   
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\toprule
Permisario & Localización & Inicio de  & {Longitud} & {Volumen} & {Volumen} & {Inversión} & Estatus \\
&             & Operaciones &           &{Promedio} & {Promedio}&             &         \\
&             &                    & {\si{\kilo\metre}} & {\si{\milli\metre^3\day}} & {(MMpcd)} & {(Mdd)} \\                   
\midrule
\endhead

Gasoductos de Chihuahua & San Isidro-Samalayuca & Dic-97 & 37.7 & 5663.4 & 200.0  & 15.7 & Operando \\
Igasamex San José Iturbide & Himilpan-San Luis Potosí & Mar-98 & 3.0 & 13643.5 & 482.0 &  & Operando \\
FINSA Energéticos & Matamoros, Tamaulipas & Jun-98 & 8.4 & 36.2 & 1.3 & 0.9 & Operando \\
Pemex Gas y Petroquímica Básica & Naco-Hermosillo, Son. & Mar-99 & 339.0 & 3113.0 & 109.9 & 22.1 & Operando \\
Pemex Gas y Petroquímica Básica & Sectores Cárdenas, Minatitlán, Veracruz, Cd.Mendoza, Tlaxcala, V. de Carpio, Salamanca, Guadalajara, Madero, Reynosa, Monterrey, Torreon y Chihuahua & Jun-99 & 8704.0 & 140035.1 & 4945.3 & 1430.3 & Operando \\
Energía Mayakan & Tabasco, Chiapas, Campeche, Valladolid, Yucatán & Sep-99 & 710.0 & 4247.0 & 150.0 & 303.0 & Operando \\
Transportadora de GN de Baja California & Otay, San Diego-Rosarito, Baja California & Jun-00 & 45.0 & 26621.0 & 940.0 & 64.8 & Operando\\
Gasoductos del Bajío & Salamanca-Aguascalientes  & Abr-01 & 204.0 & 606529.0 & 21419.3 & 39.5 & Operando \\
Gasoducto Rosarito & Los Algodones-Baja California & Sep-02 & 302.0 & 40610.0  & 1434.0 & 275.1 & Operando \\
Gasoducto Agua Prieta & Frontera México-EUA-Naco, Sonora & Dic-02 & 13.0 & 5664.0 & 200.0  & 7.7 & Operando \\
Tejas de Gas de Toluca & Palmillas-Toluca, Edo de México & Feb-03 & 123.2 & 77.0 & 2.7 & 31.0  & Operando \\
Kinder Morgan & Cd. Mier, Tamaulipas-Huinalá, Nuevo León & Mar-03 & 137.0 & 10479.3 & 370.0 & 4.1  & Operando \\
Gasoductos del Río & Frontera México - EUACCC Rio Bravo II, III y IV y Portes Gil, Tamaulipas & Ago-03 & 57.9 & 11.6 & 0.4  & 39.3 & Operando \\
Gasoductos de Tamaulipas & Reynosa-San Fernando & Nov-03 & 114.0 & 28317.0 & 1000.0 & 222.0 & Operando \\ 
Conceptos Energéticos Mexicanos & Carretera Federal Mexicali Tijuana & Dic-03 & 1.8 & 13779.0 & 486.0 &  & Operando \\
Transportadora de Gas Natural de la Huasteca & Naranjos Veracruz-Tamazunchale, S.L.P. & Dic-06 & 127.0 & 5097.0 & 180.0 & 181.0 & Operando \\ 
Energía Occidente de México, S. de R. L. de C. V. & Manzanillo-Colima Guadalajara, Jalisco & Jun-11 & 307.0 & 8495.1 & 300.0 & 360.0 & Operando \\
Tarahumara Pipeline, S. de R. L. de C. V. & Cd. Juárez-Chihuahua & Jul-13 & 389.0 & 1940.0 & 68.5 & 368.8 & Operando \\ 
Tejas Gas de la Península & Valladolid, Campeche Nizuc, Quintana Roo & n/a & & & & & En construcción \\ 
Gasoducto de Morelos & Esperanza-Venta de Carpio y Cempoala-Santa Ana & & 9542.0 & 1142.0 & 337.0  & 246.0 & En construcción \\ 
\multirow{2}{0.16\linewidth}{Gasoducto del Noreste, S. de R.L. de C.V.} & \multirow{2}{0.2\linewidth}{Agua Dulce-Los Ramones} & 1ª etapa: Dic 14 & \multirow{2}{*}{83283.0\footnote{1ª etapa: \num{28317};}} & \multirow{2}{*}{3100.0\footnote{2ª etapa \num{54966}.} } & 587.0 & 116.8 & \multirow{2}{*}{En construcción} \\ 
           &               &   2ª Etapa: Dic 15 & & & & & \\    
%\multirow{3}{0.16\linewidth}{Gasoducto de Aguaprieta} & Sasabe-Puerto Libertad & Oct-14  & 220.0 & 21806.4 & 770.0 & 172.6 & \multirow{3}{p{50pt}}{En construcción} \\
%& Puerto Libertad-Guaymas & Oct-15 & 285.0 & 14443.2 & 510.0 & 196.1 & \\
%& Guaymas-El Oro         & Ago-16 & 328.0 & 14443.2 & 510.0 &  83.7 & \\
Transportadora de Gas Natural de Zacatecas & Aguascalientes-Calera, Zacatecas & Jul-14 & 175.0 & 566.0 & 20.0 & 70.0 & En construcción \\
\addlinespace
& Total nacional & & 1058442.0 & 13889.8 & 37536.4 & 4720.9 & \\
\bottomrule     
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

I commented an attempt to use multirow within the table because it generates a compilation error. What do you suggest me to fix this mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work to use `tabularx` with no `X` columns, but I wouldn't use `tabularx` here.

This is still a bit wide but not knowing the language I can't really abbreviate any more.

```
   \documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=letter,headings=small,bibliography=totoc,DIV=12,headsepline=true,titlepage=on]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{soul}   
    \usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel} 

    \usepackage{xspace}
    \usepackage{xkeyval}
    \usepackage{array,multirow,multicol,rotating,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,longtable} 
    \newcolumntype{Z}{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
    %\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
    \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{@{}C@{}}{#1}}  
    \usepackage{rotating} 
    \usepackage{colortbl} 
    \usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx} 
    \sisetup{
    output-decimal-marker = {.},
    group-minimum-digits = 4,
    range-units = brackets,
    list-final-separator = { \translate{and} },
    list-pair-separator = { \translate{and} },
    %range-phrase = { \translate{to (numerical range)} },
    range-phrase={\,a\,}
    }
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \providetranslation [ to = Spanish ]
    { to~(numerical~range) } { a }%substitute the right word here
    \ExplSyntaxOff    
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
    \setcellgapes{1.5pt}

\newcommand\hd[1]{%
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}

\captionof{table}{Gasoductos}
\label{tab:GasoIns}

\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setlength\LTleft{-9pt plus 1fil}
\setlength\LTright{-9pt plus 1fil}
\begin{longtable}{@{}
>{\raggedright}p{0.16\linewidth}
>{\raggedright}p{0.2\linewidth}
l
S[table-format=4.1]
S[table-format=5.1]
S[table-format=7.1]
S[table-format=5.1]
l
  @{}}
\toprule
\hd{Permisario} &
\hd{Localización} & 
\hd{Inicio\\ de Oper-\\aciones} &
\hd{Longitud\\\si{\kilo\metre}} &
\hd{Volumen\\Promedio\\\si{\milli\metre^3\day}} & 
\hd{Volumen\\Promedio\\(MMpcd)} &
\hd{Inversión\footnote{A millones de dólares de 2014.}\\(Mdd)} & 
\hd{Esta-\\tus} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\toprule
\hd{Permisario} &
\hd{Localización} & 
\hd{Inicio\\ de Oper-\\aciones} &
\hd{Longitud\\\si{\kilo\metre}} &
\hd{Volumen\\Promedio\\\si{\milli\metre^3\day}} & 
\hd{Volumen\\Promedio\\(MMpcd)} &
\hd{Inversión\\(Mdd)} & 
\hd{Esta-\\tus} \\
\midrule
\endhead

Gasoductos de Chihuahua & San Isidro-Samalayuca & Dic-97 & 37.7 & 5663.4 & 200.0  & 15.7 &Op. \\
Igasamex San José Iturbide & Himilpan-San Luis Potosí & Mar-98 & 3.0 & 13643.5 & 482.0 &  &Op. \\
FINSA Energéticos & Matamoros, Tamaulipas & Jun-98 & 8.4 & 36.2 & 1.3 & 0.9 &Op. \\
Pemex Gas y Petroquímica Básica & Naco-Hermosillo, Son. & Mar-99 & 339.0 & 3113.0 & 109.9 & 22.1 &Op. \\
Pemex Gas y Petroquímica Básica & Sectores Cárdenas, Minatitlán, Veracruz, Cd.Mendoza, Tlaxcala, V. de Carpio, Salamanca, Guadalajara, Madero, Reynosa, Monterrey, Torreon y Chihuahua & Jun-99 & 8704.0 & 140035.1 & 4945.3 & 1430.3 &Op. \\
Energía Mayakan & Tabasco, Chiapas, Campeche, Valladolid, Yucatán & Sep-99 & 710.0 & 4247.0 & 150.0 & 303.0 &Op. \\
Transportadora de GN de Baja California & Otay, San Diego-Rosarito, Baja California & Jun-00 & 45.0 & 26621.0 & 940.0 & 64.8 &Op.\\
Gasoductos del Bajío & Salamanca-Aguascalientes  & Abr-01 & 204.0 & 606529.0 & 21419.3 & 39.5 &Op. \\
Gasoducto Rosarito & Los Algodones-Baja California & Sep-02 & 302.0 & 40610.0  & 1434.0 & 275.1 &Op. \\
Gasoducto Agua Prieta & Frontera México-EUA-Naco, Sonora & Dic-02 & 13.0 & 5664.0 & 200.0  & 7.7 &Op. \\
Tejas de Gas de Toluca & Palmillas-Toluca, Edo de México & Feb-03 & 123.2 & 77.0 & 2.7 & 31.0  &Op. \\
Kinder Morgan & Cd. Mier, Tamaulipas-Huinalá, Nuevo León & Mar-03 & 137.0 & 10479.3 & 370.0 & 4.1  &Op. \\
Gasoductos del Río & Frontera México - EUACCC Rio Bravo II, III y IV y Portes Gil, Tamaulipas & Ago-03 & 57.9 & 11.6 & 0.4  & 39.3 &Op. \\
Gasoductos de Tamaulipas & Reynosa-San Fernando & Nov-03 & 114.0 & 28317.0 & 1000.0 & 222.0 &Op. \\ 
Conceptos Energéticos Mexicanos & Carretera Federal Mexicali Tijuana & Dic-03 & 1.8 & 13779.0 & 486.0 &  &Op. \\
Transportadora de Gas Natural de la Huasteca & Naranjos Veracruz-Tamazunchale, S.L.P. & Dic-06 & 127.0 & 5097.0 & 180.0 & 181.0 &Op. \\ 
Energía Occidente de México, S. de R. L. de C. V. & Manzanillo-Colima Guadalajara, Jalisco & Jun-11 & 307.0 & 8495.1 & 300.0 & 360.0 &Op. \\
Tarahumara Pipeline, S. de R. L. de C. V. & Cd. Juárez-Chihuahua & Jul-13 & 389.0 & 1940.0 & 68.5 & 368.8 &Op. \\ 
Tejas Gas de la Península & Valladolid, Campeche Nizuc, Quintana Roo & n/a & & & & & En c. \\ 
Gasoducto de Morelos & Esperanza-Venta de Carpio y Cempoala-Santa Ana & & 9542.0 & 1142.0 & 337.0  & 246.0 & En c. \\ 
Gasoducto del Noreste, S. de R.L. de C.V. & Agua Dulce-Los Ramones & 
\hd{1ª etapa:\\ Dic 14\\2ª Etapa:\\ Dic 15} & 83283.0\footnote{1ª etapa: \num{28317};} & 3100.0\footnote{2ª etapa \num{54966}.}  & 587.0 & 116.8 & En c. \\ 
Transportadora de Gas Natural de Zacatecas & Aguascalientes-Calera, Zacatecas & Jul-14 & 175.0 & 566.0 & 20.0 & 70.0 & En c. \\
\addlinespace
& Total nacional & & 1058442.0 & 13889.8 & 37536.4 & 4720.9 & \\
\bottomrule     
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your helping, so after read the code, I guess the answer to my question is: `>{\raggedright}p{<width>}` .